# Covert video to frames, then back to video without altering the frames in python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I am writing a script in python that converts a video (let this video be *X*) into frames (*X′*) and then back into the same video (*Y*). Now, when I break video *Y* back into frames (*Y′*) the images are not equal to *X′* frames i.e. they have different hashes. I would expect them to be the same, and if being not the same is the expected behaviour, how can I make them the same?

Is there a way to go from

`video, *X* --> frames, *X′*, --> video, *Y*, --> frames, *Y′*, --> video, *Z*, --> frames, *Z′*

and so on without changing the output from its previous state such the videos *X*, *Y*, *Z* and frames *X′*, *Y′*, *Z′* are same to each other in their respective sets?

I have tried multiple video codecs (mp4, avi, mkv) and image formats (tif, jpeg, png). To my understanding, lossy compression codecs should not work by lossless such as tif are not producing consistent output either.

I have followed these [video-to-frame](https://medium.com/@haydenfaulkner/extracting-frames-fast-from-a-video-using-opencv-and-python-73b9b7dc9661) and [frame-to-video](https://www.life2coding.com/convert-image-frames-video-file-using-opencv-python/) among other tutorials but to no avail. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) and possibly also [colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorspace) conversion and [chroma-subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling). You must use a lossless workflow that also supports your colorspace (or "pixel format").

Example:

1. Output a lossless image format:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 x_%02d.tiff
   ```

   See a list of supported pixel formats with `ffmpeg -h encoder=tiff`.
2. Obtain frame hashes using the [framehash muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#framehash):

   ```
   ffmpeg -v error -i x_%02d.tiff -f framehash -hash md5 -
   #stream#, dts,        pts, duration,     size, hash
   0,          0,          0,        1,   230400, 56a4401ee8f46ef4205508ab06926bdc
   0,          1,          1,        1,   230400, 3ff51f5bef6dbf619fd0469bd29f63ec
   0,          2,          2,        1,   230400, ef51487b9905ecb4638c9901251a1dde
   ```
3. Encode video using a lossless encoder:

   ```
   ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i x_%02d.tiff -c:v ffv1 video_y.mkv
   ```
4. Output a lossless image format:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video_y.mkv y_%02d.tiff
   ```
5. Obtain frame hashes:

   ```
   ffmpeg -v error -i y_%02d.tiff -f framehash -hash md5 -
   #stream#, dts,        pts, duration,     size, hash
   0,          0,          0,        1,   230400, 56a4401ee8f46ef4205508ab06926bdc
   0,          1,          1,        1,   230400, 3ff51f5bef6dbf619fd0469bd29f63ec
   0,          2,          2,        1,   230400, ef51487b9905ecb4638c9901251a1dde
   ```

Hashes match.

Comment: If anyone wants to take advantage of multiple cores append `-threads 384` before `-i` in the commands to do so. E.g. `ffmpeg -threads 384 -i input.mp4 x_%02d.tiff`
[Source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8694)

Comment: Can the audio from `input.mp4` at step 1 be mixed into `video_y.mkv` at step 3 while maintaining their hashes? I could not do it since a set of images is not considered a stream by ffmpeg.


Also, I am not sure if I understand how input.mp4 and video_y.mkv have the same 25 fps. Is this by default or is ffmpeg somehow interpreting the correct settings from the set .tiff images?


Thank you for all that you do Mr. Ilogan.

Comment: @Rashiq Yes, `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i x_%02d.tiff -i input.mp4 -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v ffv1 -c:a copy video_y.mkv`. Default is 25 fps. If you want to change it use the `-framerate` input option. See updated answer for example. You do not need to set a frame rate when outputting the images.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!
What steps should I take to do the same for the audio, extract and merge it back into `video_y` losslessly?

Comment: @Rashiq `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 audio.wav`, `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i x_%02d.tiff -i audio.wav -c:v ffv1 -c:a flac video_y.mkv`