# NumPy array of a video changes from the original after writing into the same video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing, scikits, ffmpeg-python

I have a video (`test.mkv`) that I have converted into a 4D NumPy array - (frame, height, width, color_channel). I have even managed to convert that array back into the same video (`test_2.mkv`) without altering anything. However, after reading this new, `test_2.mkv`, back into a new NumPy array, the array of the first video is different from the second video's array i.e. their hashes don't match and the `numpy.array_equal()` function returns false. I have tried using both [python-ffmpeg](https://github.com/donnyyou/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples) and [scikit-video](https://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html) but cannot get the arrays to match.

#### Python-ffmpeg attempt:

```
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np
import hashlib

file_name = 'test.mkv'

# Get video dimensions and framerate
probe = ffmpeg.probe(file_name)
video_stream = next((stream for stream in probe['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)
width = int(video_stream['width'])
height = int(video_stream['height'])
frame_rate = video_stream['avg_frame_rate']

# Read video into buffer
out, error = (
    ffmpeg
        .input(file_name, threads=120)
        .output("pipe:", format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
        .run(capture_stdout=True)
)

# Convert video buffer to array
video = (
    np
        .frombuffer(out, np.uint8)
        .reshape([-1, height, width, 3])
)

# Convert array to buffer
video_buffer = (
    np.ndarray
        .flatten(video)
        .tobytes()
)

# Write buffer back into a video
process = (
    ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
        .output("test_2.mkv", r=frame_rate)
        .overwrite_output()
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
)
process.communicate(input=video_buffer)

# Read the newly written video
out_2, error = (
    ffmpeg
        .input("test_2.mkv", threads=40)
        .output("pipe:", format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
        .run(capture_stdout=True)
)

# Convert new video into array
video_2 = (
    np
        .frombuffer(out_2, np.uint8)
        .reshape([-1, height, width, 3])
)

# Video dimesions change
print(f'{video.shape} vs {video_2.shape}') # (844, 1080, 608, 3) vs (2025, 1080, 608, 3)
print(f'{np.array_equal(video, video_2)}') # False

# Hashes don't match
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video_2)).digest()) # b'\x88\x00\xc8\x0ed\x84!\x01\x9e\x08 \xd0U\x9a(\x02\x0b-\xeeA\xecU\xf7\xad0xa\x9e\\\xbck\xc3'
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video)).digest()) # b'\x9d\xc1\x07xh\x1b\x04I\xed\x906\xe57\xba\xf3\xf1k\x08\xfa\xf1\xfaM\x9a\xcf\xa9\t8\xf0\xc9\t\xa9\xb7'
```

#### Scikit-video attempt:

```
import skvideo.io as sk
import numpy as np

video_data = sk.vread('test.mkv')

sk.vwrite('test_2_ski.mkv', video_data)

video_data_2 = sk.vread('test_2_ski.mkv')

# Dimensions match but...
print(video_data.shape) # (844, 1080, 608, 3)
print(video_data_2.shape) # (844, 1080, 608, 3)

# ...array elements don't
print(np.array_equal(video_data, video_data_2)) # False

# Hashes don't match either
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video_2)).digest()) # b'\x8b?]\x8epD:\xd9B\x14\xc7\xba\xect\x15G\xfaRP\xde\xad&EC\x15\xc3\x07\n{a[\x80'
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video)).digest()) # b'\x9d\xc1\x07xh\x1b\x04I\xed\x906\xe57\xba\xf3\xf1k\x08\xfa\xf1\xfaM\x9a\xcf\xa9\t8\xf0\xc9\t\xa9\xb7'
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong and both the respective documentations do not highlight how to do this particular task. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the same hash requires when writing and reading a video file requires careful attention.

Before comparing the hash, try to look at the video first.

Executing your code gave me the following output (first frame of video_2):
[image]

When the input (first frame of video) is:
[image]

I suggest the following modifications:

- Use AVI container (instead of MKV) for storing `test_2` video in raw video format.
  AVI video container is originally designed for storing raw video.
  There could be a way for storing raw, or lossless RGB video in MKV container, but I am not aware of such option.
- Set the input pixel format of `test_2` video.
  Add an argument: `pixel_format='rgb24'`.
  Note: I modified it to `pixel_format='bgr24'`, because AVI supports `bgr24` and not `rgb24`.
- Select video a lossless codec for `test_2` video.
  You may select `vcodec='rawvideo'` (rawvideo codec is supported by AVI but not supported by MKV).

Note:
For getting equal hash, you need to look for lossless video codec that supports `rgb24` (or `bgr24`) pixel format.
Most of the lossless codecs, converts the pixel format from RGB to YUV.
The RGB to YUV conversion has rounding errors that prevents equal hash.
(I suppose there are ways to get around it, but it's a bit complicated).

---

Here is your complete code with few modifications:

```
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np
import hashlib

file_name = 'test.mkv'

# Get video dimensions and framerate
probe = ffmpeg.probe(file_name)
video_stream = next((stream for stream in probe['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)
width = int(video_stream['width'])
height = int(video_stream['height'])
frame_rate = video_stream['avg_frame_rate']

# Read video into buffer
out, error = (
    ffmpeg
        .input(file_name, threads=120)
        .output("pipe:", format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='bgr24')  # Select bgr24 instead of rgb24 (becasue raw AVI requires bgr24).
        .run(capture_stdout=True)
)

# Convert video buffer to array
video = (
    np
        .frombuffer(out, np.uint8)
        .reshape([-1, height, width, 3])
)

# Convert array to buffer
video_buffer = (
    np.ndarray
        .flatten(video)
        .tobytes()
)

# Write buffer back into a video
process = (
    ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height), pixel_format='bgr24', r=frame_rate)  # Set input pixel format.
        .output("test_2.avi", vcodec='rawvideo')  # Select video code "rawvideo"
        .overwrite_output()
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
)
process.communicate(input=video_buffer)

# Read the newly written video
out_2, error = (
    ffmpeg
        .input("test_2.avi", threads=40)
        .output("pipe:", format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='bgr24')
        .run(capture_stdout=True)
)

# Convert new video into array
video_2 = (
    np
        .frombuffer(out_2, np.uint8)
        .reshape([-1, height, width, 3])
)

# Video dimesions change
print(f'{video.shape} vs {video_2.shape}') # (844, 1080, 608, 3) vs (844, 1080, 608, 3)
print(f'{np.array_equal(video, video_2)}') # True

# Hashes do match
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video_2)).digest())
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video)).digest())
```

---

Result (same hash):

`True`

`b"\xd1yy\x97\x8e\xce\x13\xbcI#\xd2PMP\x80(i+5\xe1\xcd\xab\xf3f\xbe\xcd\xd5'\xbaq\xdd\x9b"`

`b"\xd1yy\x97\x8e\xce\x13\xbcI#\xd2PMP\x80(i+5\xe1\xcd\xab\xf3f\xbe\xcd\xd5'\xbaq\xdd\x9b"`

---

### Update:

**Using ffv1 encoder:**

The same hashes are achieved using the [ffv1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFV1) encoder for .mkv

- Select `vcodec='ffv1'` in the arguments of `output()`.

One more thing:

- Move the argument `r=frame_rate` from the output arguments to the **input** arguments.
  It's not intuitive... but when creating video out of frames, the frame rate should be defined as an argument of the input.

  ```
   # Write buffer back into a video
   process = (
       ffmpeg
           .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height), pixel_format='rgb24', r=frame_rate)  # Set input pixel format.
           .output("test_2.mkv", vcodec='ffv1')  # Select video code "rawvideo"
           .overwrite_output()
           .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
   )
  ```

Here is the complete code sample:

```
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np
import hashlib

file_name = 'test.mkv'

# Get video dimensions and framerate
probe = ffmpeg.probe(file_name)
video_stream = next((stream for stream in probe['streams'] if stream['codec_type'] == 'video'), None)
width = int(video_stream['width'])
height = int(video_stream['height'])
frame_rate = video_stream['avg_frame_rate']

# Read video into buffer
out, error = (
    ffmpeg
        .input(file_name, threads=120)
        .output("pipe:", format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')  # Select rgb24 instead of rgb24 (becasue raw AVI requires rgb24).
        .run(capture_stdout=True)
)

# Convert video buffer to array
video = (
    np
        .frombuffer(out, np.uint8)
        .reshape([-1, height, width, 3])
)

# Convert array to buffer
video_buffer = (
    np.ndarray
        .flatten(video)
        .tobytes()
)

# Write buffer back into a video
process = (
    ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height), pixel_format='rgb24', r=frame_rate)  # Set input pixel format.
        .output("test_2.mkv", vcodec='ffv1')  # Select video code "rawvideo"
        .overwrite_output()
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
)
process.communicate(input=video_buffer)

# Read the newly written video
out_2, error = (
    ffmpeg
        .input("test_2.mkv", threads=40)
        .output("pipe:", format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
        .run(capture_stdout=True)
)

# Convert new video into array
video_2 = (
    np
        .frombuffer(out_2, np.uint8)
        .reshape([-1, height, width, 3])
)

# Video dimesions change
print(f'{video.shape} vs {video_2.shape}') # (844, 1080, 608, 3) vs (844, 1080, 608, 3)
print(f'{np.array_equal(video, video_2)}') # True

# Hashes do match
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video_2)).digest())
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video)).digest())
```

---

Result (same hash, using your input file):

`True`

`b'\x9d\xc1\x07xh\x1b\x04I\xed\x906\xe57\xba\xf3\xf1k\x08\xfa\xf1\xfaM\x9a\xcf\xa9\t8\xf0\xc9\t\xa9\xb7'`

`b'\x9d\xc1\x07xh\x1b\x04I\xed\x906\xe57\xba\xf3\xf1k\x08\xfa\xf1\xfaM\x9a\xcf\xa9\t8\xf0\xc9\t\xa9\xb7'`

---

### Update:

**Using Scikit-Video**:

The following code sample uses Scikit-Video.
I couldn't find a way for selecting `ffv1` codec, without using `skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter`.
The implementation uses a for loop for writing the video frame by frame.

```
import skvideo.io as sk
import numpy as np
import hashlib

video_data = sk.vread('test.mkv')

# Create FFmpeg vidoe writer
writer = sk.FFmpegWriter('test_2_ski.mkv', outputdict={'-vcodec': 'ffv1' })

#sk.vwrite('test_2_ski.mkv', video_data)

# Write frame by frame in a loop
for i in range(video_data.shape[0]):
    writer.writeFrame(video_data[i, :, :, :])

writer.close()  # Close video writer.

video_data_2 = sk.vread('test_2_ski.mkv')

# Dimensions match
print(video_data.shape) # (844, 1080, 608, 3)
print(video_data_2.shape) # (844, 1080, 608, 3)

# Array elements match
print(np.array_equal(video_data, video_data_2))

# Hashes match
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video_data_2)).digest())
print(hashlib.sha256(bytes(video_data)).digest())
```

Comment: The same hashes are achieved for the frames [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481842/covert-video-to-frames-then-back-to-video-without-altering-the-frames-in-python/66497653#66497653) using the `ffv1` encoder for .mkv. But I couldn't figure out how to specify that even after reading through the documentation of ffmpeg-python, which is very convoluted in my opinion. Do you perhaps know how to specify that? Thank you for the answer. I'll play around with it a bit and then get back to you.

Comment: You are right, `'ffv1'` codec works well. Select `vcodec='ffv1'` in the arguments of `output()`.

Comment: I tried using the solution you provided word for word but I can't seem to make it work. The NumPy arrays are different and subsequently the hashes. Array shapes: `(844, 1080, 608, 3) vs (1013, 1080, 608, 3)`; Original hash: b'\xdb\x9bn\xe2\xde\xd2\xdd\x0c\xd8\xad\x86\x81\x06\xbd\x0c\x87\xeb\x0c}c\x1a%I\xcd\x16%\x9d(Y\xba\x901'; Output hash: b"\xd1yy\x97\x8e\xce\x13\xbcI#\xd2PMP\x80(i+5\xe1\xcd\xab\xf3f\xbe\xcd\xd5'\xbaq\xdd\x9b". The file I used is [here](https://fileleaks.com/jXAX8pW849/test.mkv). I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I found the problem (there is a framerate conversion issue - you are getting 1013 frames instead of 844). Solution: Move the argument `r=frame_rate` from the output arguments to the input arguments. After updating, I am getting the same hash using your input file. I updated my post.

Comment: Can I ask for your thoughts on my attempt at using the Scikit-Video for this task? I don't think I understand what is preventing that from working correctly. Thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: I never used Scikit-Video. Do you know how to select `ffv1` codec? Is it supported by  Scikit-Video?

Comment: I added a solution using Scikit-Video, but it uses `FFmpegWriter`, and it writes the video frame by frame.

Comment: I was just about to say that I had no clue what to send as the key to the `outputdict` for the `FFmpegWriter` method. I tried `encoder` like in the ffmpeg docs, `vcodec` like your example, and `c:v`. Kept getting a `Broken Pipe` error. How did you figure out `-vcodec` when it's not even in the docs? Please, teach me your ways. I want to learn.

Comment: Simple Google searching... I found an example [here](https://www.imagetracking.org.uk/2017/12/how-to-write-lossless-video-in-python/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230518/discussion-between-rashiq-and-rotem).